# How can I let someone know that the click on the link comes from my site

Tags: javascript

Hello fellow programmers. My case is - I have many links on my website, each of them directs to a different website. How can I let that website which stored its link on my website know, that the user's click comes from my website?

I've read something about `utm_source=MySite`. Is it the thing I'm looking for? 
And if so - where should I drop it? At the end of the link?

`<a href={example.com/something/utm_source=MySite}>Link</a>`?

Thank you for any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`utm_source` is a URL query string parameter that was originally part of a referrer tracking strategy invented by a company called Urchin Traffic Monitor. They were since bought by Google and the technology sort of lives on now as part of Google Analytics.

This way of tracking is not part of any Web or other standard though, mind you.

There is [some](https://support.google.com/urchin/) [information](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en) available at Google's.

Since `utm_source` is a query string variable, if you wish to use this patent-pending (that's right) strategy, these go after the pathname in the URL in your links to third parties, like:

```
<a href="http://example.com?utm_source=mydomain.com">Visit Example.com!</a>
```

That's all there is to it, really. There are other variables like you yourself mentioned that go with the `utm_source` variable.

I think also you should research other alternative solutions that may suit you better.

As a bonus, there is no need to patch all your document links manually to include the query string variable(s), just run the following statement when your document is at least interactive (`document.readyState` is not "LOADING", so the links are actually loaded):

```
for(const link of document.links) link.href = (function(URL) { URL.searchParams.set("utm_source", "mydomain.com"); return URL; })(new URL(link.href));
```

You should probably check to not include links that have no hostname or use your own domain explicitly -- no need to include referrer then, is it.

Comment: patent-pending? What does it mean? Should I avoid it then?

Comment: I am not sure myself what it would imply, you are probably safe -- if a judge decides that using query string variables of your choosing is illegal, the entire industry will be on fire. See https://support.google.com/urchin/#topic=2583495

Comment: Sorry, the above link to the supposed page on the patent pending nature of the tracking strategy in question (AFAIR) is dead, thanks Google.